# display red dot on textfield javafx

Tags: java, javafx

The `searchField` is a TextField that only accept numbers. I did it with the code below.

```
searchField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
  if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
    searchField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
  }
});
```

Now I want the TextField to show a red warning when user tries to input a letter. Like this..[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTx9R.png)

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried in order to show a "red" warning ? Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I would like to mentioned that your approach of evaluating the Field's content is not recommended. Instead use a `TextFormatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) has a class called [CustomTextField](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/CustomTextField.html) that allows you to set a `Node` on the left or right side of the `TextField`.

As for the logic (taking some from a previous answer), here's what you would do:

```
ImageView errorView = new ImageView();
errorView.setImage(new Image("error.png"));
CustomTextField searchField = new CustomTextField();
searchField.setRight(errorView);
searchField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
        searchField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
        searchField.setStyle("-fx-text-box-border: red; -fx-focus-color: red ;");
        errorView.setVisible(true);
    }else if(!searchField.getStyle().equals("")){
        searchField.setStyle("");
        errorView.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your looking for if you set the style of the border to red when its incorrect it will simulate what you want to see and set it back to normal when the key event is correct

```
searchField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
        searchField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
        searchField.setStyle("-fx-text-box-border: red; -fx-focus-color: red ;");
        //stopIcon.setVisible(true)
    }else if(!searchField.getStyle().equals("")){
        searchField.setStyle("");
        //stopIcon.setVisible(false)
    }
});
```

If you want the stop sign like in your picture you can probably load an icon in and set it to visible and not visible with the code stiling

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own Control as following :

-First you need to put your `TextField` in a `Layout`.

-Then add a `Label` with the exclamation sign aligned to the center.

-After that you need to edit the shape of the `Label`.

-And finally make a condition to the visibility of the this one to appear according to the input.